# DLL dependencies for portable C/C++ application for Windows

Tags: c++, c, dll, portable-executable

I want to create a light-weight portable application in C/C++ for Windows. I don't want to statically link everything because I want to keep the size of exe as small as possible. I also use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com) to track the DLL dependencies of my exe file.

My question is that what are the **list** of DLL dependencies that an application can have and stay portable across different versions of Windows? With this list at hand I can check the output from Dependency Walker with the list and choose which libraries to link statically and which to link dynamically. I prefer the list contain OSes from Windows XP higher, but having Windows 98 in mind is also interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a basic Win32 application in something like Visual Studio and check the dependencies with Dependency Walker. Those are your base dependencies. All of the standard Win32 DLL files will be required, including `user32.dll`, `kernel32.dll`, and so on. (Although some of this varies, depending on what you want the application to do. In some cases, you can get away with only `kernel32.dll`, but you won't be able to show a window on the screen. Probably a fairly useless app.)

Keep in mind that the last version of Visual Studio that can compile applications that run on Windows 98 is Visual Studio 2005. Visual Studio 2008 can target a minimum of Windows 2000, while VS 2010 can target a minimum of Windows XP SP2. You'll need to either use an older version of the compiler, or edit the executable file's PE header manually to change the subsystem field.

If you're really into things like this (although it's honestly a waste of time) you should investigate Matt Pietrek's LIBCTINY, originally from [an article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb985746.aspx) published in MSDN Magazine back in January of 2001. This little library makes it theoretically possible to use the [`/NODEFAULTLIB` compiler flag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3tz4da4a.aspx) in order to avoid linking to the CRT.

Comment: Is this basic application Portably runnable in Windows XP or 98?

Comment: @Sina: It depends on what version of Microsoft's C/C++ compiler (bundled with Visual Studio) that you use to compile it with. I address that more completely in my answer. The later versions of the CRT call functions that simply don't exist on the older versions of Windows.

Comment: Thanks Cody. I conclude that CRT is the main problem for creating portable programs. Is it true? or are there other kinds of problems with standard Win32 DLLs also? e.g., their incompatibility in different Windows versions.

Comment: @Sina: Yes, the CRT is definitely the main problem. But there are potential snags with the Win32 DLLs, too. It all depends on which functions your app calls. You have to make sure to either *only* call functions that are available on all of your target platforms (which means you can't use fancy new features of Windows Vista, for example, even on OSes where they are available), or you'll have to `typedef` all of the functions you want to use and go through the tedium of loading the DLLs dynamically with `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are linking to standard Windows DLLs then there's no issue because the DLLs are already present on the target systems.

For other DLLs, if you have to distribute the DLL then your total executable code size will be greater than if you had used static linking. You only end up with smaller executable code size if you have multiple applications that use common libraries.

In other words, although dynamic linking sounds seductive, old fashioned static linking may be better for you.

Now, if you are concerned about linking to a C runtime then you could consider using mingw which can link against the Windows C runtime which is present on all systems.

Comment: What exactly does mingw do differently here than Microsoft's compiler?

Comment: @Cody mingw can use msvcrt.dll from the Windows installation (i.e. the one in system32) as its C runtime. Visual Studio, has to use its own runtime. MSVC6 was the last version that could use the Windows C runtime if I recall.

Comment: Thanks David for the point. I think the C Runtime is a headache for creating portable programs. I checked utorrent.exe with Dependency Walker and I saw that it is actually using msvcrt.dll also.

Comment: @Sina You can always link it statically. You have to balance size of executables with convenience. That said, if you can use a tool chain that links against Windows msvcrt.dll then I think that's a fine solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using VC. Microsoft provides the list you're looking for in MSDN. See:

- [Redistributing Visual C++ Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235299%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)
- [Determining Which DLLs to Redistribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kche8ah%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Note that the list changes based on VC's version (you can choose yours on the top of the pages). Also, on modern versions of Windows, it is *advised* to properly install the runtime dlls using VCRedist_*.exe - it would probably make your programs less portable than you wish, but it's a one-time installation of (sort of) system components, that no-one will ever have to uninstall.